# Mockery doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I am trying to use Mockery to determine if my controller was properly called.

I make the call to the function from within my test case and the method returns properly. However, Mockery doesn't seem to catch that call.

I tried doing the call using both $this->call and $this->client->request. Both calls return the result, so Mockery should count the call to the controller.

```
public function testIndex()
{

  /**$entity = \Entity\Classes\Entity::get();
  var_dump($entity);    **/ 
  //This works, and is returning all the entities for that entity

  $headers = array();

  $mock = Mockery::mock('\Entity\Classes\Entity');

  $mock->shouldReceive('index')->once();

  $crawler = $this->custom_request('GET', '/entity/entities/114', $headers); 

  //echo $response = $this->client->getResponse()->getContent();
  //This also works, so the call is being made. custom_request calls $this->client->request method 

  //$this->call('GET', 'http://myurl:1000/entity/entities/114');
      //This alternate method to make the call also work

  $this->assertResponseOk();

}
```

Error:

```
1) ClassTest::testIndex
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method index() from       
Mockery_0_Entity_Classes_Entity should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you'd be injecting the mock into something, right now it's just sitting around in your test method and not being used. If you're using Laravel, you either need to be replacing the actual `Entity\Classes\Entity` in the IoC container with the mock, or if `Entity\Classes\Entity::index` is a static method, you need to use alias mocking, but I wouldn't recommend that, it's a can of worms.

Edit:

Search for "alias:" on this page https://github.com/padraic/mockery/blob/master/docs/05-QUICK-REFERENCE.md for alias mocking. Note you will probably want to run tests that use alias mocking with phpunit's process isolation.

Comment: Ah. While I posted this, I was looking into some things and I also came across your response. It turns out, I do need to use alias mocking because everything is static. Can you pinpoint me a bit on alias mocking? I couldn't find anything significant on the proyect's github.

Comment: @Dynelight see answer again, added link

Comment: Dave one last question: Should filters give a problem using this? I tried adding the alias and I got a ''BadMethodCallException: Method Entity\Controllers\Entity::getAfterFilters() does not exist on this mock object'' ... Is that the can of worms you meant?

Comment: Also, when I make the call to the controller I am mocking via the GET, isn't the mock supposed to be called there?

Comment: @Dynelight afraid I'm not sure, I don't know eloquent (or your code) well enough

Comment: My controller was calling the entity in a static way. I based myself on your link and also on https://tutsplus.com/tutorial/easier-testing-with-mockery/ and now I am passing the object on the controller's constructor, that checks if I am passing a mocked object or not. The controller will then call the Entity object. However, this object calls methods from other classes. Do I need to mock them in order to test if they are being called? I can get my count assertion to work if I call local methods from within that class, but not external methods.